# Balanced Parens not returning as balanced in java

Tags: java, stack

I am testing to see if an arithmetic formula (Ex. ((5-6)/(3+2)*34) ) has balanced parentheses but my loop to check for right and left parens is not returning as equal. I am testing it by just entering "()" into the console when prompted.

```
for (int i = 0; i < formula.size(); i++)
  {
    char c = formula.pop();

    if (c == ')') {
        right++;
        break;
    } else if (c == '(') {
        left++;
        break;
    } else {
        break;
    }

  }// End for loop

  //System.out.println("There are " + left + " left parens, and " + right + " right parens.");

  if (right == left)
     System.out.println("The parentheses are balanced.");
  else
     System.out.println("The parentheses are NOT balanced.");
```

my right and left variables are initialized to 0, and the output I get is that there is 1 right paren and 0 left parens.

Any thoughts? It sounded/looked right when I wrote it.

UPDATE: Here is my code updated to using a switch case instead of an if else. Still geting same output though..

```
for (int i = 0; i < formula.size(); i++)
  {
    char c = formula.pop();
     switch(c)
     {
        case ')':
           right++;
           break;   //Which breaks the switch, not the for
        case '(':
           left++;
           break;   //We don't need to do anything if it's neither.

     }// End switch      
  }// End for loop
```

UPDATE#2: Here is all of my main with the recent changes:

```
public static void main(String[ ] args) {

  //variables
  String formulaString;
  Stack<Character> formula = new Stack<Character>();
  int right = 0;
  int left = 0;

  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Welcome, enter a mathmatical formula and I will "
                    + "determine if the parentheses are balanced.\n");

  formulaString = in.next();

  for (int j = 0; j < formulaString.length(); j++) {

     formula.push(formulaString.charAt(j));

  }// End for loop

  System.out.println("Preview of the formula just entered: ");
  System.out.println(formula.display());

  System.out.println("The size of the stack is: " + formula.size());
  System.out.println("/******************************************");

  for (int i = 0; i <= formula.size(); i++)
  {
    char c = formula.pop();
    System.out.println(c);
    switch(c)
    {
       case ')':
         right++;
         break;   //Which breaks the switch, not the for
      case '(':
         left++;
         break;   //We don't need to do anything if it's neither.

     }// End switch      
  }// End for loop

  System.out.println("There are " + left + " left parens, and " + right + " right parens.");

  if (right == left)
     System.out.println("The parentheses are balanced.");
  else
     System.out.println("The parentheses are NOT balanced.");

}// End main.
```

My input that I am testing now is `(())`.
My output that I'm getting it:

```
Preview of the formula just entered: 
[(, (, ), )]
The size of the stack is: 4
/******************************************
)
)
(
There are 1 left parens, and 2 right parens.
The parentheses are NOT balanced.
```

Comment: What's `formulate.size()`? Edit: nevermind, you're using `break;` This will exit your `for` loop after the first iteration.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I am using Java Stack. it is checking the size of the Stack. The arithmetic formula is being pushed character by character into the stack.

Comment: can you print your c?
what does `char c = formula.pop();` do?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel But the break is in the if statement? Or does it not work like that.

Comment: @X-Pippes if I print the c, formula.pop() takes the first character off the top of the stack and returns what was just "popped" or removed.

Comment: the if-statement itself is automatically ended at the closing braces, this would make no difference. If you want to exit the loop (which is `for`) you use `break`, if you want to continue with the next iteration (and skip any possible statements at the end), you use `continue`. `break` is used for switch statements to prevent the waterfall effect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't want to use `break`, you want to use `continue`, but in this case it is not needed at all. Change your loop into this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < formula.size(); i++)
{
  char c = formula.pop();

  if (c == ')')
  {
    right++;
    continue; //You don't need to add this since nothing is being done after this point
  }
  else if (c == '(')
  {
    left++;
    continue; //You don't need to add this since nothing is being done after this point
  }
  //We don't need to do anything if it's neither
}
```

`break` will exit the for-loop, instead of continuing with the next item. Therefore you were only finding 1 bracket.

**Update**: The `switch`-variant, as Chris asked, where you would be using `break`, would look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < formula.size(); i++)
{
  char c = formula.pop();
  switch(c)
  {
    case '(':
      left++;
      break; //Which breaks the switch, not the for
    case ')':
      right++;
      break;
    //We don't need to do anything if it's neither. 
  }
}
```

**Update 2**:
I now see that your `for`-loop is wrong too. You are using: `for (int i = 0; i < formula.size(); i++)`. Because you use `pop`, `formula.size()` decreases every time the loop is executed, while `i` increases. Therefore your loop ends too soon. There are 2 ways to solve this. You can use a `while`-loop like this:

```
while (formula.size() > 0)
...
```

Or you can change the `for`-loop into this:

```
int formulasize = formula.size();
for (int i = 0; i < formulasize; i++)
...
```

Comment: Maybe show the `switch` variant here, where `break` is applicable?

Comment: Unless formula only contains parens, he probably doesn't want break in the `else` case either.

Comment: I switched it to the case but I am still getting an output of unbalanced showing only 1 right paren and no left parens. :( Let me post more of my code, the error must be somewhere else in my program..

Comment: @MagdaleneB. Did the first version work? And can you print `formula`? Just to be sure the input is correct.

Comment: @PatrickKostjens Ok, I just tried that and you're right, for some reason it is only printing/popping the last thing in the stack which is the right paren. I'll post another update of my code that I have..

Comment: Good answer. Definitely earned my +1.

Answer (score 0):

You have put breaks which are causing the loop to be incomplete

```
if (c == ')') {
  right++;              
} else if (c == '(') {
  left++;               
}
```